# Linking Eclipse Bookmarks view with a JFace Table Viewer

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to use the default Eclipse `Bookmarks` view with a `TableViewer`. For example, a context menu in table gives user the option to use selected item as bookmark. And double clicking on bookmark will jump to the specified table index.

How to add or remove bookmark items in the `Bookmarks` view and set the contents of the bookmark (Description, Location, Resource, Path)?

Comment: This doesn't sound like it's related to the existing concept of Bookmarks at all. What's the TableViewer *showing*? What is its *input*?

Answer (score 1):

Bookmarks are just markers (`org.eclipse.core.resources.IMarker`) with the bookmark type (`org.eclipse.core.resources.bookmark`).

Markers are always associated with an `IResource` (usually an `IFile`) and are created and deleted using the `IResource` `createMarker` and `deleteMarkers` calls.

The Bookmarks view `org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.BookmarksView` does not offer any way to change the behavoir of the view. Double clicking an entry will always open the associated resource.

So what you want to do is not possible with bookmarks.

Comment: I see from this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336737/how-to-add-a-marker-on-the-ruler) that one needs to add marker to a IResource (in our case as a bookmark). However I have a 'TableViewer' which is not an IResource. Its unfortunate but looks like I need a custom view.